# Why isn't Apache Basic authentication working?

Tags: apache-2.2

I just upgraded Apache from it's 2003 build, to a squeaky-clean, brand-new 2.4.1 build. All seems pretty good except for one glaring thing:

In my httpd.conf file I have the following:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AuthType      Basic
    AuthName      "Enter Password"
    AuthUserFile  /var/www/.htpasswd
    Require     valid-user
</Directory>
```

This should allow only users in the specified auth file to access the server - just as it had under the older version of Apache. (Right?)

However, it's not working. Requests are granted with no authentication provided. When I switch logging to LogLevel Debug, for the accesses, it says:

```
[Sat Mar 24 21:32:00.585139 2012] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10733:tid 32771] mod_authz_core.c(783): [client 192.168.1.181:57677] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sat Mar 24 21:32:00.585446 2012] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10733:tid 32771] mod_authz_core.c(783): [client 192.168.1.181:57677] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

I really don't know what this means - and I (to the best of my knowledge) don't have any "Require all granted" or "" statements in any of my files.

Any ideas why this isn't working, or where to debug??

UPDATE:

I have a virtualhost on the SSL port which allows proxying. When I put the *same* entries inside the

```
<proxy *>
```

clause in the virtualhost config, it *works*. It doesn't seem to work in the

```
 <Directory>
```

clause. I then tried putting under other Directory clauses (specific for other directories) and that *didn't* work either.

**ALSO**

From Shane's questions below - I tried duplicating the root "/" block to a "/tmp" directory. The /tmp directory works CORRECTLY!! So - this problem is specific to the root directory only???

Comment: What other `<Directory>` blocks do you have applying to the requests that aren't working?

Comment: I just put one for the root "/" directory, which should apply to the entire server. I have tried adding one to the user home directory (per mod_userdir) and had the same results with that.

Comment: @ShaneMadden - on your question - I tried duplicating the root "/" block to a "/tmp" directory. The /tmp directory works CORRECTLY!! So - this problem is specific to the root directory only???

Comment: I suspect that there's a more-specific `<Directory>` block elsewhere in your Apache config that's taking precedence over the one that you've set for `/`.

Comment: I just grepped everything - nothing. These config files were *very* minimal modifications to Apache's newly-installed defaults.

Comment: Try defining the `<Directory>` within the `<VirtualHost>` block for your site - and point it to your `DocumentRoot` instead of `/`.  Let's see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Digest authentication on a fresh 2.4 install.  Looking closely at the documentation on Apache's site, it looks like the authentication directives need to be in a `<Location>` tag rather than a `<Directory>` tag.  See the documentation for [the AuthBasicProvider directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider).

Comment: This is not correct.  mod_auth_basic and mod_auth_digest can be used in <Directory> and <Location> as well as <File> <If> and <Proxy>.  In the documentation for Apache 2.4 -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider Under "Context" is listed "Directory" which indicates all of the above valid containers. -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context

Comment: It shouldn't be correct, but it worked for me. Maybe it's because in the Directory part there were other settings (es. RewriteRule)

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same problem, and nothing from this post have helped me, so I'll add my 2 cents.
In my case (apache 2.4) the problem was in the sequential **Require** directives.

By default, if you have more than one **Require** directives, they are considered as `<RequireAny>`

In my `<Directory>` I've had

```
Require ip 192.168.100.0/24 10.9.8.0/24
Require valid-user
```

So auth request didn't appear if IP was correct.
I've had to switch **Require** logic from `<RequireAny>` to `<RequireAll>` and it seems that now everything works correct.

```
   <Directory /var/www>

      DirectoryIndex index.html
      Options -Indexes

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "hidden data"
      AuthBasicProvider    file
      AuthUserFile /opt/httpaswd
      <RequireAll>
        Require ip 192.168.100.0/24 10.9.8.0/24
        Require valid-user
      </RequireAll>
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 7):

jscott's answer is incorrect. Apache 2.4 most certainly **does** allow authentication directives in `<Directory>` containers.  Moreover, this is the only secure way to implement authentication, as `<Location>` containers can be accessed in different ways, allowing your authentication to be circumvented if you're not careful.

For the sake of reference, here is a sample container I am using on a production system:

```
<Directory "/srv/http/my_domain.org/html/secret-stuff">
    Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "staff"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/private/secret-stuff.htaccess
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 7):

Also check if there isn't accidentally  another

```
    Require all granted
```

elsewhere in the same Directory config. 
it may be overriding your

```
    Require     valid-user
```

Comment: stupid me, that was the case in my example. Just found it via google. Thank you @commonpike.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing a provider for AuthBasic.  Try adding a line like:

```
AuthBasicProvider    file
```

Once you have this working you may want to look at the `Satisfy` directive.  This can be used to allow local access without a password while requiring a password for Internet access.

EDIT:  I use an include file for BasicAuth to enable password-based remote access to content that is normally not available from the Internet.  You may not want the `Satisfy` directive. This is my `/etc/apache2/basicauth.conf` file:

```
# Basic authorization configuration include file 
# Enable basic auth access for remote users
AuthName             "Authentication Required"
AuthType             Basic
AuthBasicProvider    file
AuthUserFile         /etc/apache2/httpd.passwd
Require              valid-user
Satisfy              any
```

I also have an `/etc/apache2/allow_local.conf` include file for IP-based authentication.

```
# Common local access block - Allow all local addresses
Order deny,allow
Deny  from all
Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

To enable them I use these includes.

```
Include /etc/apache2/allow_local.conf
Include /etc/apache2/basicauth.conf
```

You may want to try adding to the authorization specification.  This works with my test configuration.

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

Comment: Tried it - still doesn't work :-O

Comment: If I just include your files as-is, I get an error: "AuthName not allowed here" - as you can't specify these directives anywhere (like outside a "Location", "Directory", or "Proxy" clause. Or am I missing something? If I do include it inside the "Directory" clause - again - I am let in without any credentials.

Comment: If I only put a "deny from all" in the "directory" clause, I am denied access (as you'd expect). If then include your FIRST script in the directory clause, I am unconditionally allowed access. If I remove the "satisfy" in your script, I am unconditionally denied.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it's likely to be an Apache bug; in my case, the problem showed up after an update, and disappeared after a subsequent update, but I had to add this at the bottom:

```
Deny from all
```

That's scary that Apache could open security holes like this :(

Comment: `Deny from all` is an apache 2.2 setting. 

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

Comment: yes changing security-related directives in a backward-incompatible way is baaaaaad

Comment: I'm surprised that apache didn't give me a warning for basically ignoring BasicAuth directives before I added this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`<Directory "/">
  ...
</Directory>`

Instead of:
`<Directory />
  ...
</Directory>`

Meaning: encapsulate the root symbol with double quotes. Otherwise, you might be closing the  tag with that slash.

Comment: Directory '/' is the entire operating system.. You may want /var/www/html or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was building a sandbox to test some basic Apache features.  When I tried setting up the authentication, my requests were also being granted without any authentication needed.

After trying the other answers, what ended up working for me was **clearing the cache** in my web browser.  After that I was required to authenticate as expected.

I know it's very simple and specific to my case, but I figured I would post in case others have a similar issue later on.