# Apache 2.4: after upgrading from 2.2, password-secured folders are no longer secured and I can't figure out how to make it so

Tags: apache-2.4

My apache 2.4 vhost configuration looks like this:

```
<Directory />
   Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /http/mystuff.org/html>
   Options FollowSymLinks Indexes Includes
   XBitHack on
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /http/mystuff.org/html/secretstuff>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "archives"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/private/secretstuff.htaccess
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

The `Require valid-user` directive is simply ignored (i.e. anyone can get to the secretstuff folder without having to authenticate) and I can't figure out how to make it work.  I've tried adding `Require all denied` to the beginning of the , tried using `<Location>` instead of `<Directory>` (someone on stackexchange suggested this), but nothing seems to work.  I even tried

```
<RequireAll>
   Require valid-user
</RequireAll>
```

thinking this might be needed because of the `Require all allowed` in the parent directory, but this didn't work, either.  I've read through the apache 2.4 documentation a half a dozen times now and haven't a clue as to why my directives to require a valid user are being ignore.  The same configuration worked fine in apache 2.2.

Finally, I believe I have all the necessary modules loaded:

```
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
```

Comment: Here is the link to the question/response suggesting that you have to use `<Location>` instead of `<Directory>`.  From testing on another system I know this isn't true, and it didn't work for me in any case.

http://serverfault.com/questions/373104/why-isnt-apache-basic-authentication-working

Answer (score 0):

OK, the preceding configuration works.  I previously had a typo in the directory location, and the page was cached on the browser after that.  Total noob mistake.